# Confused about Configuring Linux Path Environment /etc/profile.d/*.sh being Executed Twice?

Tags: environment-variables, path, bashrc, profile, bash-profile

I am trying to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to CentOS here are the code I tried

```
export |grep PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

no output, normal...

```
echo "$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

why there is output here??

and if I

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH :/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' >> /etc/profile.d/path.sh
source /etc/profile.d/path.sh
```

Now the same path will present twice........

```
export |grep PKG_CONFIG_PATH
declare -x PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

So if the path hasnt been setup yet where is that $PKG_CONFIG_PATH coming from?

**Update Edit:**
The first part of the problem is not actually matters because after restarting the variables are cleared

For the really problem I think it is because the files inside profile.d are been called twice once by /etc/bashrc once by /etc/profile. One may ask WTH??Why is that happened?BUG??TYPO??

Answer (score 2):

This is the difference between *exported* and *non-exported* environment variables.

The `export` command only lists *exported environment variables*, i.e. those variables that are marked as inheritable by child processes, either because the shell has inherited them from its parent process, or because the `export` or `declare -x` command has been used to mark them as exportable.

Non-exported variables are useful in scripts, as you can use them within the script, but they won't clutter the environment of any child processes.

To set a non-exported variable, you can use the `name=value` syntax alone:

```
$ FOO=bar
$ echo $FOO
bar
export | grep FOO
$
```

You can later mark the variable as exportable:

```
...
$ export FOO
$ export | grep FOO
declare -x FOO="bar"
```

Classic Bourne shell in fact *required* you to initialized environment variables in this two-step fashion: first set the value, then mark it as exportable. So you may still see this syntax in shell scripts aiming for maximum portability:

```
FOO=bar
export FOO
```

Modern shells allow doing it in a single step:

```
$ export FOO=bar
```

So, in your case, you must have had previously executed a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, either manually, or within a *sourced* script, or as part of your login scripts.

Comment: I am suspecting that too.May be at some point I set the environment variable without out export.But those should be temporary restart the system will remove those variable but it is not the case and I cant find it hard code written in any of the files. of course I can export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig exclusively but that means any of the pre existing path are not included(if there is by any chance) and it is not safe.

Comment: Adjustment.If I remove the line **export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH :/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig** both echo and export return nothing but if I add them back the path will show twice,see that problem.

Comment: Indeed it looks like your profile scripts are being executed twice: maybe once to initialize the X11 environment at GUI login (the shell that runs your `~/.Xsession` script or the `gnome-session` command, or whatever desktop environment you're using), and then another time when opening a shell window?.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have two solution:

1. Remove these code from /etc/bashrc

   ```
   for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
     if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "$PS1" ]; then
           . "$i"
        else
          . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
     fi
   done
   ```

   problem is I dont know why these code needs to be here in the first place there maybe some side effects after removing them.
2. Just use direct assignment in /etc/profile.d/*.sh

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
   ```

   of course this will exclude any preexisting path,not a standard practice.

Neither of them seems to be perfect solution any better suggestion?

**Update :**

Doing ① will cause this error message to appear after each command enter at the terminal

```
 bash: __vte_prompt_command: command not found
```